# Ambiguous reference to member 'create(_:value:update:)'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using RealmSwift in my project. 
When trying to update one of the parameters of an existing object, I get the following error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'create(_:value:update:)'

And here is the code I'm working on:

```
        let newProduct = ShoppingBagObject(value: [product.id, product.name!, product.price!, product.oldPrice!, product.weight!, count])
        try? realm?.write {
            realm?.create(newProduct, value: ["count": 3], update: .modified)
        }
```

I want to update the 'count' parameter only.

And here is the reference from realm.io official documentation:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.create(Book.self, value: ["id": 1, "price": 9000.0], update: .modified)
    // the book's `title` property will remain unchanged.
}
```

EDIT: 
Here is my model class:

```
class ShoppingBagObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var price = 0
    @objc dynamic var oldPrice = 0
    @objc dynamic var weight = 0
    @objc dynamic var count = 1

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your create statement doesn't match the docs. You have `realm?.create(newProduct` and the docs are `realm.create(Book.self`. Realm needs to know what type of object to create so you pass Object.self as the first parameter

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```swift
try? realm?.write {
    realm?.create(ShoppingBagObject.self, value: ["id":product.id, "count":3], update: .modified)
}
```

From the docs:

> If a Book object with a primary key value of ‘1’ already exists in the
>   database, then that object will simply be updated. If it does not
>   exist, then a completely new Book object will be created and added to
>   the database.
>
> You can also partially update objects with primary keys by passing
>   just a subset of the values you wish to update, along with the primary
>   key

Comment: Great answer. One thing; the OP just wants to update the *count* property - in that case all you need is the primary key and the field to update. `realm.create(ShoppingBagObject.self, value: ["id": 1, "count": 3], update:.modified)` - the rest of the fields will not be affected.

Comment: Ah yes, so the `id` is essentially acting as a primary key. So long as the `id` is passed in the dict, it knows which object on the back end to update. Good call.